# Maintaining the separator in awk output

Tags: awk, syntax, separator

I would like to subset a file while I keep the separator in the subsetted output using ´awk´ in bash.

That´s what I am using:

The input file is created in R language with:

```
inp <- 'AX-1   1    125  AA  0.2  1 AB -0.89 0 AA 0.005 0.56
        AX-2   2    456  AA  0   0 AA -0.56 0.56 AB -0.003 0
        AX-3   3    3445  BB  1.2  1 NA  0.002 0 AA 0.005 0.55'
inp <- read.table(text=inp, header=F)
write.table(inp, "inp.txt", col.names=F, row.names=F, quote=F, sep="\t")
```

*(So fields are separated by tabs)*

The code in bash:

```
awk {'print $1 $2 $3'} inp.txt
```

The result:

> AX-11125
>
> AX-22456
>
> AX-333445

Please note that my columns were merged in the `awk`output (and I would like it to be tab delimited as the input file). Probably it is a simple syntax problem, but I would be grateful to any ideas.

Comment: As an aside: while `{'print $1 $2 $3'}` syntactically happens to work, it's better to put the entire Awk script into single quotes: `'{print $1 $2 $3}'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print $1, $2, $3 }'
```

or

```
awk '{ print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 }'
```

Written one after another without an operator between them, variables in awk are concatenated - `$1 $2 $3` is no different from `$1$2$3` in this respect.

The first solution sets the output field separator `OFS` to a tab, then uses the comma operator to print separated fields. The second solution simply sprinkles tabs in there directly, and everything is concatenated as it was before.